# Issue with power shell solution checker script

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration

I'm getting following error while running the powershell solution checker script for CI:

```
Get-PowerAppsCheckerRulesets : An error occurred while sending the request.
At C:\MSDynamics\BuildScripts\PowerShell\SolutionCheckerCI.ps1:31 char:13
+ $rulesets = Get-PowerAppsCheckerRulesets -Geography Europe -TenantId  ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-PowerAppsCheckerRulesets], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,Microsoft.PowerApps.Checker.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetPowerAppsCheckerRulesets
```

Comment: Does the machine running this script sit behind a corporate proxy perhaps?

Comment: We’ll be creating a Powershell script and invoking it from teamcity build.. It is showing error while trying to establish connection to Azure

Comment: And does the teamcity build server have direct access to the internet, or does it need to connect through a proxy?

Comment: No direct access. It need to use the proxy which is whitelisted, still it is not working.